# Can't figure out how to get history from javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The mail is transferred to the client with Javamail (no problem here).

The problem that there is no trace (history) of this message in my mailbox.

How can I have the sent mail saved in my mailbox history?

**EDIT**

When i try the code sample. i got this error ( in the store.connect(...) )
i had all the jar needed : activation mail et smtp
can you help please?

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Not a Store Provider: protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@1be2d65; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Oracle
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:302)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:279)
    at saba.utils.Mail.main(Mail.java:175)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking.  If you're asking why, when you send a message with JavaMail, you don't have a copy of that message in your "Sent" folder, the answer is that JavaMail doesn't do that for you automatically.  Some servers will do that for you, but not all.  Normally your JavaMail program needs to save a copy of any sent message in the "Sent" folder explicitly.  See the [msgsend.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).

Comment: Hi. thanks for your replay.It's exactly my question.